# Pickle load on off thread blocks main thread

Tags: multithreading, pickle

Calling `ObClass`'s `prep()` blocks the main thread until the pickle finishes. Why? How can I unpickle data in the background?

Try this at home:

```
def PrepFn(ob):
    ob.lock.acquire(1)
    try:
        print "begin load"
        f = open(ob.filename, "rb")
        ob.data = cPickle.load(f)
        print "end load"
    except Exception as msg:
        print(str(msg))
    ob.lock.release()
    f.close()


class ObClass:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.filename = filename
        self.data = None
    def prep(self):
        thread.start_new_thread(PrepFn, (self,))
    def get(self):
        self.lock.acquire(1)
        self.lock.release()
        return self.data

def make_data(filename):
    print "generating data"
    data = np.asarray(np.random.normal(size=(10000, 1000)))
    print "writing data to disk"
    f = open(filename, "wb")
    cPickle.dump(data, f)
    f.close()

def test(filename):
    x = ObClass(filename)
    x.prep()
    for i in xrange(1000):
        print i
    print "get data"
    data = x.get()
    print "got data"
```

To see it in action, do

```
filename = "test.pkl"
test.make_data(filename)
test.test(filename)
```

For me, this goes:

```
0
1
2
 begin load
3
4
[...]
83
```

followed by a long pause, followed by

```
 end load
84
85
86
[...]
996
997
998
999
get data
got data
```

Comment: Are you calling wait after start_new_thread ? 
Or are you trying to lock the lock again ?

Comment: Nope. No call to wait, and I am not touching the lock until much later.

Comment: Could you please paste some more code ?

Comment: I made a complete example that you can run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), which means everything done by interpreter in one process has to be confined in one CPU core.

When you start the IO thread, it is being scheduled but not started immediately. Hence the delay.

When your thread starts, it triggers IO interrupt. IO is done by external C routine, so your IO thread can release the GIL. This then enables your main thread to run and to keep printing until 83.

Then your IO call from C routine returns the data stream, which is caught by your Python IO thread. When the Python IO thread runs and parses the data stream into Python object, your main thread needs to wait, which causes the pause. (`cPickle` usually takes double RAM to unfold object, so if you monitor `top`, you can see the real-time execution of object unfolding)

When your IO thread finishes parsing data, your main thread starts again to print to the end and call get.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I'm not sure how to get around the problem though -- or can I? Is it not possible to do unpickling on a background thread?

Comment: It is an official advice from Python community to use multiprocessing instead of threading. That said, if your process is heavily IO-bound, threading is still viable. A general suggestion is to split data into two pickles. Is there a reason that you need pickle instead of text? Usually the way it works for threading in Python is IO -> text deserialize + compute -> IO. You are instead doing IO + cPickle deserialize -> compute -> IO + cPickle deserialize. Text serialization like json can be fast too (using ujson).

Comment: My objects are huge, and I can't find a way to do pickling in shared memory between processes. Ultimately I'd have to somehow transfer the data over to the other process, which I suspect would require serializing/deserializing which probably means very little time saved. I am not sure what you meant by the last part about the ordering.

Comment: In threading in one CPU core, you want at least one thread to be releasing the GIL during all time in execution. Performance gain is based on careful design to achieve this. That's why IO-bound job benefits from threading even with GIL, since IO are done mostly by external routine and kernel devices. That means you want to start threads that are mostly doing IO, leaving compute thread to deserialize data and do meaning computation. cPickle.load on file is not purely IO, it's IO + heavy deserialization.

Comment: Here is one way that may work: split the pickle into two pickles, let IO thread read files into file object created from a io.ByteIO, which is in memory. Have your compute thread do loading on the ByteIO file. This will enable puerly IO threads and purely compute threads. You need two pickles for performance gain in useful computation besides print test output